# jQuery Validate, how to know when it's valid?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form, and I would like to know if it validates while not submitting it. I need the value.

```
 var validation = $(idFormulario).validate({
   errorClass: 'jqInvalid',
   errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        return false;
   },
  success: function(e){
       return false; //not submit
  }
});
```

It doesn't work. How can I check if form is valid?

Comment: Use `valid()` method to check the validity of fields - https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

Comment: Also, [read the documentation for `success`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#success), it has nothing to do with submission of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the **[above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510323/validate-jquery-how-to-know-it-success/40510424#comment-68262564)** you've to use **[`valid()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)**.

> **Description:** `valid()` Checks whether the selected form is valid or whether all selected elements are valid.

Example :

```
$(idFormulario).valid();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why @SaumyaRastogi ?!! we make content here for the future readers and not just for the author of the OP.. Thanks for your intervention.

Comment: This content could be found in the link supplied in the first comment, we don't want to encourage the OP to ask low quality questions that simply could be answered by looking at the documentation.

Comment: That why `flag` is under every post, and you could use it anytime when you feel that it's necessary. (and downvoting the correct answer is not a good habit since it's not made for this purpose, agreed?)